# How to build qt webkit ot webengine from source?

Tags: c++, qt, qtwebkit, qtwebengine

Please can u give me a step by step instrunctions on how to build qt webkit or webengine from source, I've been searching for hours , and thanks in advance

**NOTE :**I already installed qt but without the webkit

Comment: I just build it while building Qt. I believe you need python, perl and ruby installed to do that.

Comment: @drescherjm I aleardy got qt installed

Comment: That doesn't mean you can't build Qt.

Comment: The same way you build any other module from source.

Comment: @drescherjm why would i do that if I can only build the webkit ?

Comment: Also, if you have Qt without the webkit, you are probably using the mingw version, which **can't** build the webkit on windows (which is why its missing).

Comment: @ddriver yup I'm using the mingw version, Holy shit !!!!

Comment: Get the MSVC version. You can use it without visual studio, just get the VS build tools. It will come with webengine prebuild.

Comment: @ddriver I already have visual studio 2013 with the build tools all available of course so can I build it ? I mean can I change the compiler in Qt creator and build it ?

Comment: webengine build with MSVC won't work with Qt build with mingw. You will have to build the entire Qt. Or just download an offline installer for a qt version prebuilt with msvc2013: http://download.qt.io/official_releases/qt/5.7/5.7.0/

Comment: @ddriver may I ask which version shall I download if I want to develop for windows phone , android , and desktop ?

Comment: No single version of the offline installer will do the trick. Either download and install all offline versions you need, or select which ones you want from the online installer. For webengine or webkit on windows, you will need msvc. That's google's doing, the webkit/engine for each platform can only be built with its native toolchain.

Comment: Lastly, note that the webengine is not available on mobile platforms, you will have to use the webview instead.

Comment: @ddriver I already can't develop for WinRT because it needs a minimum host Windows 8.1 while I have Windows 7 , so it seems I can't develop apps for my phone, dem luck , Thank u man so much for the help

Comment: Well, nobody forced you to buy a phone platform that has 0.7% market share the last quarter. It is effectively dead :)

Comment: @ddriver Dad bought it , and the only reason why I'm using it and it's disgusting market is its big screen , it's really suitable for reading Pdfs, and I don't wanna bother dad :P

Comment: You could run windows 8.1 in a VM just to build apps. You will need like 50 spare gigs of storage.

Comment: @ddriver the problem isn't the hdd gigs it's this shitty ass computer with 2 gigs of ram and an intel pention dual core and no graphics card :D